# docker exits image imediately no package named rhino

Tags: r, docker, shiny, dockerfile, shinyapps

I am trying to launch a shiny app and use docker.
I have a `Dockerfile` and `renv.lock` file. Building the docker image gives no errors and all packages are installed prompting `ok` in the terminal after installation.

When running a docker container it exits imediately and promts the error:

```
* Project '/app' loaded. [renv 0.15.5]
> options(shiny.port=3838); rhino::app()
# Bootstrapping renv 0.15.5 --------------------------------------------------
* Downloading renv 0.15.5 ... OK (downloaded source)
* Installing renv 0.15.5 ... Done!
* Successfully installed and loaded renv 0.15.5.
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘rhino’
Calls: loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
```

the package `rhino` is however found inside the `renv.lock` file.

I have tried to rebuild twice without cache and it has not helped. Using `renv::restore()` has not helped either.

Dockerfile:

```
# Use R 4.2.0
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.2.0

# Install system libraries of general use
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
sudo \
libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
libcairo2-dev \
libxt-dev \
libssl-dev \
libssh2-1-dev \
libpq-dev \
libxml2-dev \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  
RUN R -e "install.packages('renv')"
  
# Set work dir
WORKDIR /app
COPY renv.lock renv.lock

# Restore all renv packages
RUN R -e 'renv::restore()'

# Copy project to image
COPY . .

# Expose port 3838
EXPOSE 3838

# Run app
CMD ["R", "-e", "options(shiny.port=3838); rhino::app()"]
# CMD ["R", "-e", "options(shiny.host='0.0.0.0'); options(shiny.port=3838); rhino::app()"]
# CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/home/app', host = getOption('shiny.host', '0.0.0.0'), port = 3838)"]
```

Snippet of the renv.lock file (>1k lines)

```
"rhino": {
      "Package": "rhino",
      "Version": "1.1.0",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "9db64442690b12f94ae73f6b561c9139",
      "Requirements": [
        "box",
        "cli",
        "config",
        "fs",
        "glue",
        "lintr",
        "logger",
        "purrr",
        "renv",
        "rstudioapi",
        "sass",
        "shiny",
        "styler",
        "testthat",
        "withr",
        "yaml"
      ]
    },
```

Comment: can you share the docker file

Comment: oh . What was the issue ?

Comment: When running the container it exits imediately and the log prompts the error:
```there is no package called 'rhino' ```

Comment: Is this issue fixed or u mean to say its not fixed yet?

Comment: can you share the renv.lock file?